# Phrases from birds

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

We have two pictures.  The top is a bird that promises to ????
The bottom is a poster from a local business that promises to ????
The first is a well-known phrase, the second a variation.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first image is that of a

> [Black Turnstone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_turnstone)

So I think that this bird promises to

> [Leave no stone unturned](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/leave%20no%20stone%20unturned)

The bottom image is

> A common tern superimposed on a marijuana leaf

So perhaps the business promises to

> [Leave no turn (tern) unstoned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Turn_Unstoned)

Comment: Exactly right...